# draggable, resizeable and hideable ASP.Net Gridview

Tags: webforms

I would like to know how can I make the columns of a GridView draggable, resizeable and hideable. I don't know too much about JavaScript so if anyone can provide me with a open source solution I'll be more than thankful because this is quite an emergency to me.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend reading the [faq#dontask] to find out more about what kinds of questions to ask here; It's a great place to get real help with concrete, specific problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing out of the box I can think of.

most webforms controls render some horrendous html, so using the [css friendly adapters](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/) will make working with the gridview html a much better experience.

from there you can use the [jquery-ui interactions](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) to implement draggable, resizeable and hideable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but yesterday I've tried all afternoon to search for examples about moving columns of gridview with jquery and I had no success.

Comment: no, you probably wouldn't find that specific example. instead you would need to adapt the dragable jquery interaction to an html table/column. then you would be able to create the affect you want. BTW: jquery doesn't care about the control being rendered by Gridview. all jquery cares about is the html.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to read about that.